# Best way for giving id's and classes in html

Tags: html, css

So let's assume that we have a large project with a lot of pages and we have to add one html page to that.

After creating page I saw that some of id's and classes I use appears in other pages as well. So giving css styles to that id's make a huge problems for me. 
So what is the best way to giving id's and classes that probability of doubling in project will be smallest?

One way is to add page name to attribute. So, instead of

```
id="button"
```

we will have

```
id="mypage-button"
```

But in this way id's and classes become larger and less readable. 
Another approach is to give full path to that component in CSS and minimize probability of doubling identifiers. For example, instead of giving in CSS

```
#myTable
{
height:300px;
}
```

Now I will give

```
#myBigDiv > #AnotherDiv .tables #myTable
{
height:300px;
}
```

But this way is slower and I will loose a lot in speed.
Placing my own css file in my page doesn't solve problem because having some property written I don't know have any other property(for example, margin) given in css files that are given in layout.
What do you think, what is the best way for this?

Comment: you dont need to give page specific name to ids and class you have to give conceptual name like "closeLink" , "mainDiv", "btnSumit" etc...

Comment: And how can I be sure that those id's doesn't given in any other pages too?

Comment: if you develop whole system you have to take care of it if you want 4 place a same style than give than a 1 name and different style choose different name

Comment: System isn't developed by me. I only want to add some pages to it)))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to add a class to your body tag. So with the example above, you'd use

```
.myPage #button {}
```

Comment: I've must write .myPage in every place of css code... But any way it's a best solution still)))

Comment: @mesiesta - there is no better solution - if you need to override the styles of previous selectors you need to increase the specificity of your new style - there is no other way to do it with css than using an extra class/id.

Answer (score 0):

I, personally, like to use a global.css, forms.css, and then separate CSS files for individual pages containing specific CSS for that page. Then a simple function can be used to add those pages to your  from your business end.

Answer (score 0):

how about multiple classes like `class="button page1"` using the second class to indicate page (easier to create automatically whule creating the page) and then in the css using a combination of id and classes

```
#button1.page1{
 somestyle
}
```

even better use scss to write the css - would be much easier for for multiple pages site

Comment: Take care with this approach as chained selectors are buggy in older IE browsers.